# DNN Mobile WAP site

Tags: mobile, dotnetnuke, wap

I have posted on the DNN site and on the DNN Creative forums for help with this and not getting much joy there.

I need to build a DNN Mobile site (not using mobiNuke) for our client. I would say I am about 80% complete with the actual site and in the process of testing now.

I have put the site through ready.mobi and I am failing horribly! I have followed some of the suggestions and changed the DTD to an XHTML MP dtd.

The site is still heavy with DNN resources such as javascript files and other DNN resources files so I need to know how I can strip this out. At the moment, when the WAP site loads, I am getting sizes of 140kb which of course is highly unacceptable.

I need to cater for the lowest common denominator which means that although it would be just wonderful if everyone was on an iPhone or Galaxy S this post would not even be here.

Has anyone built a DNN Mobile Wap site? Can someone give me some pointer on how to optomise the site please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out WAPL (http://wapl.info).

Allows you to create a site in a device independent mobile markup language, so you can deliver to all phones.

Also passes the .mobi test so you'll be covered there as well!